# My verification Code from Drop down is not Verifying Role

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5g4n.png)

int count = 0;
        String[] CRI = {
                "Select ROLE.",
                "0 - ABCD",
                "1 - EFMK",
                "2 - XYZV"};

```
    WebElement box = CRIDrpDwn;

    List<WebElement> Info = box.findElements(By.tagName("option"));

    System.out.println("Total Role: " + Info.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < Info.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Actual Result: " + Info.get(i).getText());
    }

    for (WebElement we : Info) {
        for (int i = 0; i < CRI.length; i++) {
            if (we.getText().equals(CRI[i])) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (count == CRI.length) {
        System.out.println("PASS: CRI Information Matched");
    } else {
        System.out.println("FAIL: CRI Information NOT Matched");
    }
    // softAssert.assertAll();

}
```

Attachment CRI[\]\[1\]/>

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: JeffC --Actually, I was trying to verify 3 roles from the dropdown with this code. but verifying elements are like this..    0-xyz, 1-ABC, 2- KLM. so my question is this code is not verifying the  0-xyz, 1-ABC, 2- KLM this element from the dropdown. could you please help me out with this issue.

Comment: You haven't explained your scenario or posted an HTML. I'm not sure how we're going to be able to help you.

Comment: JeffC --Actually, I was trying to verify 3 roles from the dropdown with this code. but verifying elements are like this.. 0-xyz, 1-ABC, 2- KLM. so my question is this code is not verifying the 0-xyz, 1-ABC, 2- KLM this element from the dropdown. could you please help me out with this issue

Comment: JeffC-- I added a screenshot top of the code.. its include the html code..let me know if you need anything

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `Select` class to handle any `SELECT` tag. Try the code below.

```
String[] expectedIssues = { "Select Client Reporting Issue...", "0 - ABCD", "1 - EFMK", "2 - XYZV" };
List<WebElement> options = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ClientReportingIssue"))).getOptions();
if (expectedIssues.length != options.size())
{
    // count of issues did NOT match
    System.out.println(
            "FAIL: CRI issues count failed. Expected: <" + expectedIssues.length + "> but there were <" + options.size() + ">");
}
else
{
    // count of issues matched
    System.out.println("Total Role: " + options.size());
    boolean pass = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < options.size(); i++)
    {
        if (!options.get(i).getText().equals(expectedIssues[i]))
        {
            pass = false;
            continue; // once it fails, quit the for loop
        }
    }
    if (pass)
    {
        System.out.println("PASS: CRI Information Matched");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("FAIL: CRI Information NOT Matched");
    }
}
```